# Reliably disabling internet access on Windows 7 and up

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line, nic

I'm trying to write a script that requires turning off the Internet entirely and then turning it back on. I'd like it to work in as many cases as possible...

- support for Window 7 and up
- if multiple Internet connections are on (like WiFi and LAN)
- regardless of how these connections are named
- limited user account, UAC?

`ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`, as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/846520/365353), do not work with 2 internet connections. `/release` disables the active connection (say WLAN) but the computer falls back on the LAN connection and you're still online.

```
$connectedAdapters = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionStatus = 2"
$connectedAdapters | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name disable
```

My questions are:

- Is `NetConnectionStatus = 2` a reliable proxy for internet access, and is it available on Windows 7 and up, regardless of the brand of your NIC?
- Is this compatible with a limited user account with UAC on? I think so...
- On my machine this query also catches VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter. Is it a problem if I disable/enable it too?
- Are `Get-WmiObject` and `Invoke-WmiMethod` are available on Windows 7 and up, right?

Comment: @JaquelineVanek Windows 8 and up :(

Comment: not sure but v5 is available for win7 now. alsoq using standard account might be tricky if possible at all

Comment: Why? And what does "internet access" mean? Disabling any connected adapter would also cut you off from any internal network you're connected to, internet-connected or not. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm aware of that, that's what I want, like Airplane Mode. The script will run locally, as part of a boxstarter script.

Comment: @JaquelineVanek I know but I want to distribute the script and support folks who are still on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions are not entirely settled, but I've developed a script that works:

[PowerShell Internet Connection helper functions: **Go-Offline, Go-Online, Test-InternetAccess**](https://gist.github.com/akaleeroy/5f7f2024b03e85e0f27a063357ada711)

```
#Requires -Version 2.0

function Test-InternetAccess {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Tests connectivity by pinging Google DNS servers once
  .DESCRIPTION
    Uses Test-Connection to ping a host, with -Quiet for returning a boolean. The default is a highly available Google DNS server (8.8.4.4)
  .EXAMPLE
    Test-InternetAccess
  .EXAMPLE
    Test-InternetAccess example.com
  .INPUTS
    None.
  .OUTPUTS
    Boolean
  #>
  param (
    [String]
    $RemoteHost = "google-public-dns-b.google.com"
    )
  Test-Connection -Computer $RemoteHost -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet
}


function Go-Offline {
  <# 
  .SYNOPSIS
  Disables your internet connection
  .DESCRIPTION
  Finds all network adapters that appear connected and disables them, taking you offline. Later on you can re-enable just those adapters, because they've been stored in an XML file. Connected adapters are detected through WMI. A NetConnectionStatus value of 2 means Connected. 7 means Media Disconnected.
  .EXAMPLE
    Go-Offline
  .INPUTS
    None.
  .OUTPUTS
    None.
  .LINK
    https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/07/use-powershell-to-identify-your-real-network-adapter/
  .LINK
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx
  #>
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
  param()
  $XMLLocation = "$env:TEMP\Disabled-NICs.xml"

  if (Test-InternetAccess) {
    $connectedAdapters = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionStatus = 2"
    # Go offline
    $connectedAdapters | Invoke-WMIMethod -Name disable 1>$null
    # Save which adapters were connected at the time
    $connectedAdapters | Select Name, DeviceID | Export-Clixml -Path $XMLLocation -Force
    Write-Output "You've been taken offline!"
    Sleep 1
  } else {
    Write-Output "Connection already down..."
    Sleep 1
  }
}

function Go-Online {
  <# 
  .SYNOPSIS
  Re-enables your internet connection
  .DESCRIPTION
  Finds all network adapters that were previously disabled by Go-Offline and enables them. This information is persisted in a temp file.
  .EXAMPLE
    Go-Online
  .INPUTS
    None.
  .OUTPUTS
    None.
  .LINK
    https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/07/use-powershell-to-identify-your-real-network-adapter/
  #>
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
  param()
  $XMLLocation = "$env:TEMP\Disabled-NICs.xml"

  if (!(Test-InternetAccess)) {
    # Get the NICs that have been previously disabled
    $connectedAdapters = Import-Clixml "$env:TEMP\Disabled-NICs.xml" | Select -ExpandProperty DeviceID | ForEach {Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "DeviceID = $_"}
    # Get back online
    $connectedAdapters | Invoke-WMIMethod -Name enable | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Internet access restored!" # Triggers early, before actual re-connection
    Sleep 1
  }
}
```

Tested on Windows 7.